# Self playing console Blackjack game with four players

Tags: c#, beginner, console, playing-cards

I want to clean this code to be more production ready. What can be improved, added or removed?

```
 enum Suits {Spades, Hearts, Diamonds, Clubs}
 class Card {

    public string Value { set; get;}
    public Suits Suit {get; set;}
 }


 class Player
 {
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public List<Card> Cards { get; set; }


     public int CalculatePoints()
     {
         int points = 0;
         int aces = 0;

         foreach (Card c in Cards)
         {
             if (c.Value == "A")
             {
                 aces++;
                 // points++;
             }
             else if (c.Value == "J" || c.Value == "Q" || c.Value == "K") points += 10;
             else points += int.Parse(c.Value);
         }

         if ((points - 21) <= 10)
         {
             for (int j = 0; j < aces; j++)
             {
                 if (j == 0) points += 11; // Adding at least one 11
                 else points += 1;  // the rest can only be 1s
             }
         }
         else
         {
             points += aces; //if we do not have a space for an 11 then lets just add 1s
         }

         return points;
     }
 }

 class Program
 {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         Player Dealer = new Player
         {
             Name = "Dealer",
             Cards = new List<Card> {
                new Card{Value= "J", Suit = Suits.Spades},
                new Card{Value= "9", Suit = Suits.Hearts}
             }
         };

         Player Billy = new Player
         {
             Name = "Billy",
             Cards = new List<Card>{
                new Card{Value="2", Suit = Suits.Spades},
                new Card{Value="2", Suit = Suits.Diamonds},
                new Card{Value="2", Suit = Suits.Hearts},
                new Card{Value="4", Suit = Suits.Diamonds},
                new Card{Value="5", Suit = Suits.Clubs}
            }
         };

         Player Lemmy = new Player
         {
             Name = "Lemmy",
             Cards = new List<Card>{
                new Card{Value="A", Suit = Suits.Spades},
                new Card{Value="7", Suit = Suits.Hearts},
                new Card{Value="A", Suit = Suits.Diamonds}
            }
         };

         Player Andrew = new Player
         {
             Name = "Andrew",
             Cards = new List<Card>{
                new Card{Value="K", Suit = Suits.Diamonds},
                new Card{Value="4", Suit = Suits.Spades},
                new Card{Value="4", Suit = Suits.Clubs}
            }
         };

         Player Carla = new Player
         {
             Name = "Carla",
             Cards = new List<Card>{
                new Card{Value="Q", Suit = Suits.Clubs},
                new Card{Value="6", Suit = Suits.Spades},
                new Card{Value="9", Suit = Suits.Diamonds}
            }
         };

         Console.WriteLine("Dealer's Points = {0}", Dealer.CalculatePoints());
         Console.WriteLine("==========================");
         //Output the winner
         Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Billy's Points   = {0}   |  {1}", Billy.CalculatePoints(), getWinner(Dealer, Billy)));
         Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Lemmy's Points   = {0}   |  {1}", Lemmy.CalculatePoints(), getWinner(Dealer, Lemmy)));
         Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Andrew's Points  = {0}   |  {1}", Andrew.CalculatePoints(), getWinner(Dealer, Andrew)));
         Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Carla's Points   = {0}   |  {1}", Carla.CalculatePoints(), getWinner(Dealer, Carla)));
         Console.ReadLine();

     }

     //Calculate the winner
     private static string getWinner(Player dealer, Player player)
     {
         if (player.CalculatePoints() > 21)
         {
             return "Looses";
         }
         else if (dealer.CalculatePoints() > 21)
         {
             return "Wins";
         }
         else if (player.Cards.Count == 5)
         {
             return "Wins : Has 5 cards";
         }
         return dealer.CalculatePoints() > player.CalculatePoints() ? "Looses" : "Wins";
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the rules of Black Jack so I won't comment the calculations.

You should have an enum for faces as you have for suits:

```
enum Suits { Spades, Hearts, Diamonds, Clubs }
enum Faces { Two = 2, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King, Ace }

class Card
{

  public Faces Face { set; get; }
  public Suits Suit { get; set; }
}
```

It is easier to read and is less error prone.

---

The `Player` could have a `Points` property that could be recalculated by `CalculatePoints()` when necessary to avoid the overhead when recalculating it every time it's needed but not necessarily changed:

```
class Player
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<Card> Cards { get; set; }

  public int Points { get; private set; }

  public void CalculatePoints()
  {
    int points = 0;
    int aces = 0;

    foreach (Card c in Cards)
    {
      if (c.Face == Faces.Ace)
      {
        aces++;
        // points++;
      }
      else if (c.Face == Faces.Jack || c.Face == Faces.Queen || c.Face == Faces.King) points += 10;
      else points += (int)c.Face;
    }

    if ((points - 21) <= 10)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < aces; j++)
      {
        if (j == 0) points += 11; // Adding at least one 11
        else points += 1;  // the rest can only be 1s
      }
    }
    else
    {
      points += aces; //if we do not have a space for an 11 then lets just add 1s
    }

    Points = points;
  }
}
```

... but that may be a bad design to have the client to recalculate the Points when needed. Instead you can hide the list of `Card`s so the `Player` can control when the list of cards changes and recalculate the `Points` accordingly:

```
class Player : IEnumerable<Card>
{
  private List<Card> m_cards = new List<Card>();

  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Points { get; private set; }
  public int CountOfCards => m_cards.Count;

  private void AddOneCard(Card card)
  {
    if (!m_cards.Contains(card))
    {
      m_cards.Add(card);
    }
  }

  public void AddCard(Card card)
  {
    AddOneCard(card);
    CalculatePoints();
  }

  public Player AddRange(params Card[] cards)
  {
    foreach (Card card in cards)
    {
      AddOneCard(card);
    }

    CalculatePoints();

    return this;
  }

  public bool RemoveCard(Card card)
  {
    bool result = m_cards.Remove(card);
    CalculatePoints();
    return result;
  }

  private void CalculatePoints()
  {
    int points = 0;
    int aces = 0;

    foreach (Card c in m_cards)
    {
      if (c.Face == Faces.Ace)
      {
        aces++;
        // points++;
      }
      else if (c.Face == Faces.Jack || c.Face == Faces.Queen || c.Face == Faces.King) points += 10;
      else points += (int)c.Face;
    }

    if ((points - 21) <= 10)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < aces; j++)
      {
        if (j == 0) points += 11; // Adding at least one 11
        else points += 1;  // the rest can only be 1s
      }
    }
    else
    {
      points += aces; //if we do not have a space for an 11 then lets just add 1s
    }

    Points = points;
  }

  public IEnumerator<Card> GetEnumerator()
  {
    return m_cards.GetEnumerator();
  }

  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
  {
    return GetEnumerator();
  }
}
```

In this way the `Player` controls it hand of cards and the surroundings can view, but not modify it without the `Player`s knowledge.

A `Player` can then be created like this:

```
  Player dealer = new Player { Name = "Dealer" }.AddRange(
    new Card { Face = Faces.Jack, Suit = Suits.Spades },
    new Card { Face = Faces.Nine, Suit = Suits.Hearts });
```

---

```
getWinner()
```

should be named in `PascalCase`:

```
private static string GetWinner(Player dealer, Player player) {}
```

---

It's OK to have the dealer as a seperate variable, but you can simplify the code, if you create an array or list for the players:

```
  List<Player> players = new List<Player>
  {
    new Player
    {
      Name = "Billy",
      Cards = new List<Card>
      {
        new Card{Face= Faces.Two, Suit = Suits.Spades},
        new Card{Face= Faces.Two, Suit = Suits.Diamonds},
        new Card{Face= Faces.Two, Suit = Suits.Hearts},
        new Card{Face= Faces.Four, Suit = Suits.Diamonds},
        new Card{Face= Faces.Five, Suit = Suits.Clubs}
      }
    },
    new Player
    {
      Name = "Lemmy",
      Cards = new List<Card>
      {
        new Card{Face= Faces.Ace, Suit = Suits.Spades},
        new Card{Face= Faces.Seven, Suit = Suits.Hearts},
        new Card{Face= Faces.Ace, Suit = Suits.Diamonds}
      }
    },
    new Player
    {
      Name = "Andrew",
      Cards = new List<Card>
      {
        new Card{Face= Faces.King, Suit = Suits.Diamonds},
        new Card{Face= Faces.Four, Suit = Suits.Spades},
        new Card{Face= Faces.Four, Suit = Suits.Clubs}
      }
    },
    new Player
    {
      Name = "Carla",
      Cards = new List<Card>
      {
        new Card{Face= Faces.Queen, Suit = Suits.Clubs},
        new Card{Face= Faces.Six, Suit = Suits.Spades},
        new Card{Face= Faces.Nine, Suit = Suits.Diamonds}
      }
    }
  };
```

You can then display the result like this:

```
  dealer.CalculatePoints();
  Console.WriteLine("Dealer's Points = {0}", dealer.Points);
  Console.WriteLine("==========================");

  foreach (Player player in players)
  {
    player.CalculatePoints();
    Console.WriteLine($"{$"{player.Name}'s", -10} Points   = {player.Points}   |  {GetWinner(dealer, player)}");
  }
  Console.ReadLine();
```

---

You should of course divide the `main()` method into meaningful methods like:

```
static void Main() 
{
  Player dealer = CreatePlayer("dealer");
  List<Player> players = CreatePlayers("Billy", "Lemmy", "Andrew", "Carla");
  ShowResult(dealer, players);
}

static Deck deck = new Deck();

static Player CreatePlayer(string name)
{
  // TODO: create a player and select cards from a `Deck` of cards randomly
}

static List<Player> CreatePlayers(params string[] names)
{
   return names.Select(name => CreatePlayer(name)).ToList();
}

class Deck
{
  Stack<Card> _cards = new Stack<Card>(); // Jokers???

  private void Initialize() {...}

  public void Shuffle() { // TODO: shuffle the card stack randomly }

  public Card Pop() { return _cards.Pop(); }

  // ... etc.
}
```